# Changes made to Azure Functions(C# Script) don't get reflected in Output

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have developed and published Azure Function in C# Script(.csx) using *Azure Functions Core Tools*. It is working fine. Now whenever I made changes to Azure Function and publish it again, changes are reflected in the files on Azure but when I run that function at that time changes made to the function are not reflected in output. After sometime, when I test again it works fine with new changes.

Does anyone has idea why does this happen?
How can I publish my Azure Function with changes so next time whenever I run my Azure Function new version of Azure Function will get run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For shared source files that are outside of the function directory (which is watched for changes by default) you can indicate that the directory should be watched by adding it to the `watchDirectories` array in your `host.json` file.

You could use the following code:

```
{
    "watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]
}
```

A set of [shared code directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#watchdirectories) that should be monitored for changes. **Ensures that when code in these directories is changed, the changes are picked up by your functions.**

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working. Still changes are not detected.